# How to put text from website into a textview

Tags: android, web-services, android-webview

I must take a text from this URL:http://diavolivicenza.blogspot.it/2013/10/il-ritorno-di-michele-valbusa-07102013.html and i must show only the text and the image into a layout. For example I want to change the color of the text or the size. I want only the text and the image. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to perform this
1 ) Make Http Request in an AsyncTask
2 ) Parse the response you will get from that url like this

```
while((text = stream.readLine()) != null )
{
    result += text ;
}
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
```

Comment: Can you do a program that does want I ask and sent me to e-mail or in another way?thanks